# yii2 datatables client Options fixed Header

Tags: datatable, yii2

i wan't to use yii2 datatable widget
How i use options **fixed Header** in **Yii2** **Datatable**

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
'fixedHeader'=>[
    'header'=>false,
    'footer'=>true,
],
```

after define the table. and refer the documentation in this link
https://datatables.net/reference/option/